# Deleting a single row takes too long

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

We have a table with 6 million rows fed by several robots (executing INSERT queries 24x7).

Occasionally we need to delete a row. I can select a row to delete in 2-3 milliseconds via a non-clustered index on my `guid` column, like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [table_name] 
WHERE guid='1655E84F-DBB3-4B53-8F2A-4E2DB350742F'
```

However, this corresponding `DELETE` statement takes more than 10 seconds:

```
DELETE FROM [table_name] 
WHERE guid='1655E84F-DBB3-4B53-8F2A-4E2DB350742F'
```

The time difference happens consistently, no matter what row I use. There are no triggers or foreign keys or anything else I can find that might cause this issue, but there are six other indexes.

How can I improve this to run in a similar time as the `SELECT` query?

Comment: I would start by looking at the query plan. Can you [Paste The Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/)

Comment: Did you look for blocking? Did you look at the wait type of the request while it is running? Are there triggers on the table? Foreign keys (especially with cascade)? How many _other_ indexes?

Comment: There are no triggers or FK's on the table but there are 6 other indexes related with other columns of the table

Comment: Are INSERTs as slow as DELETEs?

Comment: I suspect it's just blocking, waiting its turn to be able to access the row amid all of that write activity. Have you considered soft deletes?

Comment: @RhythmWasaLurker, if blocking is the culprit, a soft delete (update) will have the same issue.

Comment: The INSERT process takes around 3-4 sec... I suppose this is also too long

Comment: Yes the fact that an insert takes 3-4 seconds definitely sounds like a problem too. @DanGuzman I didn't mean to conflate the two - was just thinking a soft delete would at least alleviate the pressure on all the indexes because they wouldn't all have to be updated, in the case that part of the sluggishness is due to maintaining the indexes and _not_ due to blocking.

Answer (score 0):

By using a UNIQUE clustered index for the GUID in the table instead of a nonclustered index.

In facts, UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEXES order the table by rows.
NON CLUSTERED index is an outside index that need to seeks the index and then returns to the table.

The fact also that your index is not an UNIQUE one let's think the optimizer that there is many rows which is logicaly false when using an UNIQUE index.

Comment: But CLUSTEREDness and UNIQUEness are not equivalent - you can have a NONCLUSTERED INDEX with UNIQUE constraint. OP did not tell that it is NOT UNIQUE.